# Single getter function for multiple/all variables/collections

Tags: java, anylogic

Is it possible to build a function that takes any string and returns the corresponding variable/collection? I have around 54 private collections in one class, which I need to read from another class. The names of the needed collections are known. The easiest way would be to set each collection to public, but I assume there was a reason the original creator did set them to private. Since they are so many I'm too lazy to access them all through dedicated getters or using a switch-function.

Edit: I'm not using an ordinary GUI Java development environment. I'm working with the software AnyLogic, which doesn't have a menu for creating getters/setters.

Comment: You could put the collections inside a Map under specific names (keys). Then you access them by those names (keys). Without a specific use case, hard to tell.

Comment: Yes, using Reflection

Comment: Why are there 54 collections in one class?

Answer (score 1):

1. a) In AnyLogic, there is a special function for this purpose:
   `executeExpression( Class<T> returnType, String code )`
   To access any collection, you can use such code:
   `executeExpression( List.class, "collectionName" ).get( 0 )`

   b) The function works with public variables only, so if you define the
   collections as public, you will be able to use the function.
2. In case if collections are declared as agent parameters, you can
   access them in similar way with function
   `getParameter(java.lang.String name)`
3. Getters and Setters can  be generated in Eclipse, just copy-paste the class code to Eclipe, generate them, and copy-paste the code back to AnyLogic class code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have 54 collections in an AnyLogic class, you really should consider refactoring your underlying structure.  A few alternatives:

- Consider an array of collections (or collection of collection).  If you set up constants (static final int), you can then easily say arrayCollection[ CONSTANT ].  For example, this could be arrayWidgetsInProgess[ PRODUCT_A ] to get the collection of widgets that are of type product A.
- Consider just one collection and using lambda expressions to get the objects you are interested on the fly.  In AnyLogic that might be filter( collection, agent -> agent.attribute == attributeWeWant ).

The only time I have really needed this many collections might be the case of allowing the user to define something via a front end.  For example, if I have a model where the product types are completely user defined, they may have 10 or 100 product types.  In this case, I would tend to use a collection of collections or array or collections.  The collection of collections could be an arrayList of arrayLists, hashMap of arrayList, hashMap of hashMaps...

You should be prepared to do some instantiating of the collection of collections/arrays of collections on the class start up or in some other code.  AnyLogic's canvas will allow you to do an array of collections, but then you need to actually instantiate those collections within the array.

Comment: That's a good idea, but these collections are in a part that wasn't made by me and restructuring the collections at this point would make the whole logic faulty. I was searching for a less profound way but it seems making the collections public is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

#### Short Answer

Stop being a lazy goofball and create setters.
Every GUI Java development environment supports this operation in a menu.

#### Still Lazy

Use reflection to access the class and get the private field by name.
Try reading the [Java Class JavaDoc page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html).

Google will happily provide examples of code using reflection.
Search options include,
but are not limited to:
"Java reflection tutorial" and "Example of java reflection".